# setNotifyValue on Two BLE Characteristics

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I can't seem to setNotifyValue for more than one characteristic in the same BLE service. The app always crashes when the second setNotifyValue is called.

If I comment setNotifyValue out on either one of the characteristics and recompile, the app works well and provides a live stream of incoming data.

```dart
class DeviceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DeviceScreen({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);
  final BluetoothDevice device;
  static String CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_BTN =
      "0000ab0a-1212-efde-1523-785fef13d123";
  static String CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TEMP =
      "0000beef-1212-efde-1523-785fef13d123";

  Widget _myService(List<BluetoothService> services) {
    Stream<List<int>> btn_stream;
    Stream<List<int>> temp_stream;
    services.forEach((service) {
      service.characteristics.forEach((character) {
        if (character.uuid.toString() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_BTN) {
          character.setNotifyValue(true);
          btn_stream = character.value;
        }
        if (character.uuid.toString() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TEMP) {
          character.setNotifyValue(true);
          temp_stream = character.value;
        }
      });
    });
    return Container(
        //eric code
        child: StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
      stream: btn_stream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> btn_snapshot) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: temp_stream,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> temp_snapshot) {
            if (btn_snapshot.hasError)
              return Text('Error : ${btn_snapshot.error}');
            if (temp_snapshot.hasError)
              return Text('Error : ${temp_snapshot.error}');

            if ((btn_snapshot.data != null) && (temp_snapshot.data != null)) {
              if ((btn_snapshot.data.length != 0) &&
                  (temp_snapshot.data.length != 0)) {
                int incoming_counts = btn_snapshot.data[0];
                int incoming_temp = temp_snapshot.data[0];
                return Text(incoming_counts.toString() +
                    " " +
                    incoming_temp.toString());
              } else {
                return Text("Synced! Waiting for input");
                //return Text(btn_snapshot.data.toString() +
                //  " " +
                //  temp_snapshot.data.toString());
              }
            } else {
              return Text("Waiting to sync...");
              //return Text(btn_snapshot.data.toString() +
              //    " " +
              //    temp_snapshot.data.toString());
            }
          },
        );
      },
    ));
  }
```

I'm hoping that both "incoming_counts" and "incoming_temp" will live update as new data becomes available from the bluetooth peripheral. However, when assigning the streams, the second time calling character.setNotifyValue(true); throws an error:

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(set_notification_error, error when writing the descriptor, null))

Comment: I don't know what your flutter layer does, but if you use the standard Android APIs for Bluetooth then you must wait for the callback that indicates that the previous GATT operation has completed (onDescriptorWrite) until you can write the next descriptor to enable characteristic notifications.

Comment: Emil, I think you've helped me hack together a fix. Knowing the order that the program works through the characteristic UUID comparisons, I embedded the second time setNotifyingValue gets called in a 2 second delay. Worth noting that a 1 second delay seemed to only work conditionally. It looks like this now: 

          Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2), () {
            character.setNotifyValue(true);
          });
          btn_stream = character.value;

Comment: Well it might work in some cases, but you never know how long time the Bluetooth transaction will take (it depends on connection parameters, if packets need to be sent due to bad signal and so on). You should really try to do it the "correct" way and wait for the result before you write the next descriptor.

Comment: Absolutely, I'll keep digging around and post back if I can find a fix. I'm sure I'm not the only one to run into this.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to running multiple `setNotifyValue()` is to run it asynchronously with `await` as mentioned in this [issue thread](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/134).

```dart
await character.setNotifyValue(true);
```